# Question about exponential functions (easy one)

Tags: calculus

Can someone please explain me, why when we are looking at the function $f(x)=a^x $ , we should remember that $1 \neq a >0 $ ? (And not saying that we can't put an x that satisfies:
   $ 0 < x < 1 $ ?

Any understandable explanation will be great!

Thanks !

Comment: Disallowing $0<x<1$ wouldn't stop any problems . Taking *any* non-integer $x$ would cause problems with negative values of $a$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that we are working over the reals.

The general exponential function $a^x$ is usually defined by the formula
$$a^x=e^{x\ln a}.$$
When $a\le 0$, $\ln a$ does not exist.

As for excluding $a=1$, there is no reason to do so, except for the fact that $1^x$ is a very uninteresting function!

Comment: Congratulations, André, for 100k+. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Besides to @André's theoretical answer(+1); imagine what would be happen if $a<0$? For example if $a=-4$, what would you do with $(-4)^{\frac{m}{n}}$ wherein $n$ is even and $m$ is odd? Would we have a real number? How many fractions of this type are there in $\mathbb R$? I see the close story can be when $a=1$.